# xdebug in VSC in "Remote WSL" mode: should it respond through telnet client?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

Some context: try to set up Xdebug for VSC at Windows to debug app in docker through WSL2.

But question is way more focused.

So here is debug task in `launch.json`

```
{
  "name": "Listen for XDebug",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "port": 9001,
  "log": true,
  "pathMappings": {
    "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
  }
},
```

It's running fine, at least VSC shows "Listen for XDebug" in orange after F5.

Trying to `putty -telnet <ip> 9001` at Windows host system. Tried with "localhost" and everything `ipconfig` listed. Every time get "Network Error: Connection Refused". Actually, the same error I get after I stop task in VSC.

Also, since VSC is in "WSL mode"(so it sees all files inside WSL container) I tried to do the same but inside of WSL Ubuntu's shell. Same (negative) result.

So my question *should* I expect VSC to allow connections on port specified?